# Recieving Comparator Class type

Tags: java, sorting, oop, comparator

I have two Comparators. One for sorting words by first letter (in sort used only for vowel words)

```
public class FirstLetterComparator extends ComparatorType {
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    String upperObject1 = o1.toUpperCase();
    String upperObject2 = o2.toUpperCase();

    return upperObject1.charAt(0) - upperObject2.charAt(0);
  }
 }
```

Another for sorting by length/vowelsCount coef(used for all words in sort class)

```
public class VowelColComparator extends ComparatorType {
String vowelGroup = "AEIOUaeiou";

@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    int vCount1 = getVowelCount(o1);
    int vCount2 = getVowelCount(o2);

    float compareCoef1 = o1.length()/vCount1;
    float compareCoef2 = o2.length()/vCount2;

    return (int)(compareCoef1 - compareCoef2);
}

public int getVowelCount(String word){
    int vowelCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < vowelGroup.length(); j++){
            char v = vowelGroup.charAt(j);
            if(ch == v)
                vowelCount++;
        }
    }
    return vowelCount;
}
```

And their superclass

```
public class ComparatorType implements Comparator<String> {
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

In sort class i have two similar methods for sorting my list

```
public class SortWords {

public static void sortVowelCol(String text, String regex){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Task1:");
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next();
        if(word.matches(regex)){
            words.add(word);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(words, new VowelColComparator());

    int lineCounter = 1;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sorted Words:");
    lineCounter = 1;
    for(String w : words){
        if(lineCounter == 12) {
            System.out.print(w + "\n");
            lineCounter = 0;
        }
        else
            System.out.print(w + " ");
        lineCounter++;
    }

}
public static void sortVowelWords(String text, String regex) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

    List<String> vowelWords = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Task2: ");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next();
        if(word.matches(regex)){
            vowelWords.add(word);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(vowelWords, new FirstLetterComparator());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sorted List:");
    int lineCounter = 1;
    for(String w : vowelWords){
        if(lineCounter == 12) {
            System.out.print(w + "\n");
            lineCounter = 0;
        }
        else
            System.out.print(w + " ");
        lineCounter++;
    }
  }
 }
```

Main class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    SingletonText.getInstance().parse();
    SingletonText.getInstance().print();
      SortWords.sortVowelWords(SingletonText.getInstance().getText().toString(), "^[AEIOUaeiou].*");
    SortWords.sortVowelCol(SingletonText.getInstance().getText().toString(), "^[A-Za-z].*");
  }
 }
```

The quesuion is how can i make only one method instead of two similar methods in SortWords class? Or how to get comparator type in for Collections.sort argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need refactor two function like that:

```
public static void sortVowel(String text, String regex,Comparator comparator) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
    List<String> vowelWords = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Task2: ");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next();
        if(word.matches(regex)){
            vowelWords.add(word);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(vowelWords, comparator);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sorted List:");
    int lineCounter = 1;
    for(String w : vowelWords){
        if(lineCounter == 12) {
            System.out.print(w + "\n");
            lineCounter = 0;
        }
        else
            System.out.print(w + " ");
        lineCounter++;
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use a third parameter to define the comparator to use.

```
public static void sort(String text, String regex, ComparatorType comp) {
    // Code
    Collections.sort(words, comp);
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Passing an int to define what this method should do is really smelly. A better approach would be to pass the Comparator itself, instead.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot

Comment: Another interesting approach would be an enum which contains the usable comparators. Then one can pass an enum entry to the `sort` method. A downside is, that this would prohibit own/anonymous implementations of  `ComparatorType`.

Comment: @Tom Intersting indeed but I don't see the real plus since we're already accepting only a ComparatorType not a Comparator.

Comment: A plus would be if you like to limit the passed types to the ones you've provided and prohibit other implementations. And the user doesn't need to instantiate the `ComparatorType` implementations himself, since the enum does that.

Comment: @Tom Yes indeed. In a situation where the caller would have created another subclass of the custom comparator. Ok I get it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void sort(String text, String regex, String sortType) {

  Collections.sort(words, sorttype.equals("Vowel") ? new VowelColComparator() : new FirstLetterComparator());

    // Your code

}
```

Then we can call like this

```
SortWords.sort(SingletonText.getInstance().getText().toString(), "^[AEIOUaeiou].*", "Vowel");
SortWords.sort(SingletonText.getInstance().getText().toString(), "^[A-Za-z].*", "firstletter");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your **VowelColComparator.getVowelCount** may fail due to division by zero when there is no vowel in given string. As you are comparing ratios of length and vowel count, you can do the following:

```
float compareCoef1 = o1.length()/(vCount1+1);
float compareCoef2 = o2.length()/(vCount2+1);
```

You can use factory pattern in **ComparatorType** class. i.e **ComparatorType** class will decide which instance (comparator) to use depending upon regex. You can add as many comparators as you like.

```
public abstract class ComparatorType implements Comparator<String> {

    final public String vowelFirstLetterRegex = "^[A-Za-z].*";

    final public String vowelColRegex = "^[AEIOUaeiou].*]";


    public static ComparatorType getInstance(String regex) {
        if (regex.equals(vowelColRegex))
            return new VowelColComparator();
        else if(regex.equals(vowelFirstLetterRegex ))
            return new FirstLetterComparator();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And your SortWords class will have following method:

```
public static void sort(String text, String regex){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Task1:");
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next();
        if(word.matches(regex)){
            words.add(word);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(words, ComparatorType.getInstance(regex));

    int lineCounter = 1;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sorted Words:");
    lineCounter = 1;
    for(String w : words){
        if(lineCounter == 12) {
            System.out.print(w + "\n");
            lineCounter = 0;
        }
        else
            System.out.print(w + " ");
        lineCounter++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as everyone said, you need to pass `Comparator<String>` as the third argument to your method:

```
sortVowelWords(String text, String regex, Comparator<String> cmp) {
    //...
}
```

I'd like to suggest some improvements to comparators themselves. Using lambda syntax, they may be written far more easily:

```
static final Comparator<String> CMP_BY_FIRST_CHAR =
    Comparator.comparing(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)));

static final Comparator<String> CMP_BY_VOWEL_COEF =
    Comparator.comparing(s -> 1f * s.length() / s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiou]+", "").length());
```

In second comparator, I added explicit cast to `float` to handle possible infinity values properly.